# Car Head Unit, relay, 12V

Tags: relay, automotive, 12v

Given:

- a Head Unit that starts with a signal of voltage 12V,
- Relay Prowest 4120-1C-DC12V (12VDC, 1C, 40A / 14VDC) for switching the cigarette lighter,
- 12 volts from emergency button light :-),
- 12 volts from the ignition switch (key in the lock).

When 12 volts are supplied from the emergency light to the Head Unit - it works, ammeter reads 2.4mA, voltmeter reads 12V
When 12 volts are supplied from the ignition switch to the Head Unit - it works, ammeter reads 2.4mA, voltmeter reads 12V

When 12 volts are supplied from the emergency light to the relay - it works, ammeter reads 2.6mA, voltmeter reads 12V
When 12 volts are supplied from the ignition switch to the relay - **DOES NOT WORK**, ammeter reads 2.6mA, voltmeter reads **2V**

What could be the reason?
In addition, in all the situations described, when the ammeter is connected to the circuit (in sequence), readings appear on the display, but the Head Unit or relay does not work. What could be the reason?

[image]

Comment: What made you think measuring currents is at all relevant and how exactly do you measure them? Why aren't you measuring voltages?

Comment: I checked the current to make sure the relay doesn't use to much. Updated the question with voltage readings.
The current was measured by plugging a multimeter in series between positive wire and relay/head unit.

Voltage was measured between earth wire and positive wire